# Hosting Python Twilio server online?

Tags: python, ios, server, twilio

I'm trying to complete an iOS Swift app that send SMS with custom body. I found the following tutorial and it worked for me, however, it requires having a running python server. Is there any site that you recommend where I can host the python server and access it remotely through the web? Are there any alternatives for doing this by skipping the python server and directly sending an HTTP request from the app?

Note: This is in iOS 11 and Xcode 9 with latest version of Swift. I am also a beginner with HTTP requests and server stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to host it through [heroku](http://heroku.com/) (initially). the pricing structure is built on activity (great if you are testing and need hosting to be as inexpensive as possible), auto recognition of python code, and they give you a url that you can access remotely (i.e. someapp.heroku.com) that should allow you to access in your app.

Comment: Great, thank you! Do you know anything about PythonAnywhere by any chance? I've tried that but it does not seem so friendly at least for this type of python web app.